# How do I display this result set - it is not working

Tags: php, sql, random

Im trying to display random postings from my db on my home page, but nothing displays when I insert my code. How would I get the following code to display random rows from my db?

```
   <?php
require "connect2.php";

  $sql = "SELECT * FROM tablename
          ORDER BY RAND()";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    $userid = $row["userid"];
    $user = $row["user"];
        $city = $row["city"];
        $desc = $row["description"];
        $title = $row["title"];
    $state = $row["state"];


echo"<h3><font face='helvetica'><font size='4'><b><font color='B80000'>$title</font></font></font></b> &nbsp;<font color='A0A0A0'><a href='profile.php?id=$userid'>$user</a></font>
<font face='helvetica'><font size='3'><br>&nbsp;$desc</font></font><br>

   <h3><font color='101010'> &nbsp;$city,$state&nbsp;<font color='A0A0A0'>$date</font>  </font><a href='bid.php?id=$userid'>Bids</a>";

?>
```

Comment: Please change the title to something more explicit.

Comment: Subject is poorly phrased, down vote.

Comment: You aren't even executing your SQL query in `$sql`

Comment: Because you are not executing the query (you just assign a string to `$sql`) and `echo`ing a bunch of HTML. Have a look at the documentation: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php

Comment: I updated it. completely forgot the while

Comment: Did you copy that code somewhere? Who does still use `font` tags?

Comment: You should read some tutorials first on how to do a query...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not executing your query. You're just creating a variable that happens to contain an SQL statement. it's like saying `$win = 'Win the lottery';` and expecting your bank account to get very large numbers deposited into it.

```
$sql = 'SELECT ...';
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

$somedata = $row['somefield_from_your_database'];

echo "The value is $somedata";
```

is the basic sequence of code you need.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should execute your query:

```
<?php
require "connect2.php";

$sql = "SELECT * FROM tablename ORDER BY RAND()";

$result = mysqli_query($dbc,$query);

if

 (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_object($result)) {
    $html= <<<HTML 
<h3><font face='helvetica'><font size='4'><b><font color='B80000'>$title</font></font></font></b> &nbsp;<font color='A0A0A0'><a href='profile.php?id=$userid'>$row->user</a></font>
    <font face='helvetica'><font size='3'><br>&nbsp;$row->desc</font></font><br>

   <h3><font color='101010'> &nbsp;$city,$state&nbsp;<font color='A0A0A0'>$row->date</font>  </font><a href='bid.php?id=$row->userid'>Bids</a>
HTML;
     echo ($html);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?

    require_once("connect2.php");

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tablename ORDER BY RAND()";

    while( $row = mysql_fetch_array($sql) )
    {
        $userid = $row["userid"];
        $user   = $row["user"];
        $city   = $row["city"];
        $desc   = $row["description"];
        $title  = $row["title"];
        $state  = $row["state"];

        if (!$firstname) 
        {
            $firstname = $username;
        }

        echo "<h3><font face='helvetica'><font size='4'><b><font color='B80000'>$title</font></font></font></b> &nbsp;<font color='A0A0A0'><a href='profile.php?id=$userid'>$user</a></font><font face='helvetica'><font size='3'><br>&nbsp;$desc</font></font><br><h3><font color='101010'> &nbsp;$city,$state&nbsp;<font color='A0A0A0'>$date</font>  </font><a href='bid.php?id=$userid'>Bids</a>";
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select top 10 * from [tablename] order by newid()
```

by using this query you get random records...

Comment: since sql is picky, would I write it like SELECT top 10 * FROM table ORDER BY newid()

Comment: yes because by using this query we fetching random records to showing advertising banners..